# issue with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Query:

```
SELECT id, username,
       (SELECT username 
          FROM users 
         WHERE email = '{$email}' 
           AND activate = 0 ) AS inactive
  FROM users
 WHERE email = '{$email}'
   AND password = '{$password}'
   AND activate = 1
```

The field email is `UNIQUE` so there is no duplication in emails.

I want to output the `username` and the `id` if the combination `email,password,activate=1` exists OR output `username` as `inactive` if the combination `email,activate=0` exists.

### update: this is working

```
       SELECT id,

            (SELECT username 
               FROM users 
              WHERE email = '{$email}' 
            AND activate = 0
            ) AS inactive,

            (SELECT username 
               FROM users 
              WHERE email = '{$email}' 
            AND activate = 1
            AND password = '{$password}'
            ) AS active

            FROM users
            WHERE email = '{$email}'
```

Comment: This question becomes easier if we can return "username,id,inactive" with every query, but with "inactive" being an empty string if activate=1, and "username" being an empty string is activate=0.. Does that sound OK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
select id, 
   case activate
      when 0 then 'inactive'
      when 1 then username
   end as username
from users
WHERE email = '{$email}'
   AND (activate = 0 or password = '{$password}')
```

The case statement is present for selecting between multiple options of a column or expression

Comment: checking password takes place only when `activate=1`. thank you Amit.